# Translation of “if that’s the case”

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a nice way in Esperanto to translate the English phrase “if that’s the case”. For example:

> I suspect my neighbour is doing something illegal. If that’s the case I will call the police.

I think you can say the same thing in French with “si c’est le cas”.

I was thinking maybe you could use the word *okazo*, because that works in other situations. For example “in that case” could translated by “tiuokaze”. But “se tio estas la okazo” doesn’t sound right to me.

Comment: `Tiuokaze mi vokos la policon` is indeed fine. Full text as `En tiu kazo` maybe?

Answer (score 7):

I think that ***if that’s the case*** and ***si c’est le cas*** are idiomatic expressions. In *Tekstaro* you'll find sentences with ***se tiel,***, ***se tiel estas,*** and ***se estas tiel,*** (including the final comma):

*Mi suspektas, ke mia najbaro faras ion kontraŭleĝan. **Se tiel (estas),** mi vokos la policon.*

Using just ***se tiel,*** (without  *esti* afterwards) seems to work no matter when the action takes place:

*Ili verŝajne iros naĝi morgaŭ. **Se tiel estos,** ankaŭ mi iros.*

*Ili verŝajne iros naĝi morgaŭ. **Se tiel,** ankaŭ mi iros.*

In that sense, ***se tiel,*** and ***tiuokaze*** are very similar in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion Vidamuzo's answer is the best: ***se tiel*** is a very good expression and it is actually used.

I would like to point out that ***tiuokaze*** or ***en tiu okazo*** translate *if that happens,* while *if that's the case* might also mean *if that's how things are* with no particular event in sight, as das-g has already written: a better translation for this second meaning is simply ***en tiu kazo*** or its shorter variant ***tiukaze,*** which good speakers are careful to distinguish from ***en tiu okazo*** and ***tiuokaze.***

Answer (score 0):

*The following answer is based more on my "Sprachgefühl" than on actual Esperanto vocabulary knowledge, so take it with a grain of salt.*

Don't look for too literal translations. What you usually mean by "if that's the case" is "if that's true". So if the question is the **(current or past) factuality**, you could use

> Se mi pravas ...

or

> Se ĝi estas vera ...

It's different if you're using "If that's the case" for referring possible (but yet uncertain) occasions in the **future**.

> Someone might step on my lawn. If that’s the case, I will call the police.

> ... . Se tio okazos ...

(Don't use the noun "okazo" for that, though, as its meaning is more that of "something that happens/happened" ("occurance") or of "occasion" (concrete event) rather than that of "way things may go/be". I.e., it implies an event, not just a state.)